# Accessing macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra Time Machine backup drive on macOS 12.3.1 Monterey

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, high-sierra, monterey

I have a Time Machine backup from an older 2010 iMac running macOS 10.13.6 that I would like to access from my new Mac that's running macOS 12.3.1. When I connect the drive to my new Mac, the drive will not mount and I cannot access any of its contents.

In the past, I have just used a Windows machine I had laying around (since there is software that will allow one to access a Time Machine backup on a Windows machine), but I do not have that option anymore.

So, how does one access a Time Machine backup made on an older version of macOS (like High Sierra) on a newer version of macOS (like Monterrey)?

Comment: What do you mean with "will not mount"? Do you try to mount in Finder, or in Time Machine?

Comment: @nohillside I am basing this off of Disk Utility being able to find the volume but not being able to mount it